# Print outputs double results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the script is printing double results and I can't really pin down the problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

word = ("mission")

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('http://www.tabula.ge/en')
    soup = bs(r.text)
    div = soup.find("div", {"class": "sets"})           


    for i in div.find_all('li'):
        for text in i.find_all('a'):
            if word in text.encode('utf-8').strip():
                print text.get_text()
```

after running the script I'm getting the results twice in print output:

`Kandelaki: Georgian UN mission yet to call security council meeting`

`Kandelaki: Georgian UN mission yet to call security council meeting`

Comment: Have you checked the page that you fetch if the string you search for is actually there twice? Since you iterate over <div> and <a> maybe that is the simple case?  Also, I suggest adding your output to the question, it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you search for occurs twice in the page source.

To see the source:

- Paste in your browser `view-source:http://www.tabula.ge/en`
- Or right-click on the web page and choose "view page source"

There are two occurences of this:

```
<a href="/en/story/90354-kandelaki-georgian-un-mission-yet-to-call-security-council-meeting" data-topic="UN Security Council Meeting" data-video="false" data-date="December 1 2014, 03:13PM" data-comment-count="0" data-thumbnail="http://www.tabula.ge/files/styles/tab_thumb_featured/public/photos/2014/12/giorgi-kandelaki.jpg?itok=uKdw1i9k" data-nid="90354">
                         Kandelaki: Georgian UN mission yet to call security council meeting                    </a>
```

Comment: I've added output to the question, it still seems strange because that exact string happens only once on the page.

Comment: Yes, you see it once on the website, but in the code it is there one more time. Right click on the page and choose "view page source" and you can CTRL-F to see it. Requests reads the source.

Comment: Yes, thanks! same article happens to be on the same page in hidden tab. Have to limit search results.